# Multiple domains with cloudflare

Tags: dns, domain-name, cloudflare

One of my client has two domains names linking to a website :

Domain A

- used for emails
- used to access the website

Domain B

- used to access the website

The problem is that the client doesn't want to let us manage the DNS of the domain A and they don't want to link it to Cloudflare (we don't really know what they want to do with the DNS of this domain). They only allow us to manage the Domain B.

Is there a way, somehow, to have the Domain B linked to Cloudflare and their Domain A linked to the Domain B which is linked to Cloudflare ? Like this, if they try to access the website from Domain A or Domain B, they both benefit of Cloudflare.

(I hope I didn't say something really stupid, DNS management and CDN are still a new concept to me - if I did, please excuse me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there a way, somehow, to have the Domain B linked to Cloudflare and their Domain A linked to the Domain B which is linked to Cloudflare ? Like this, if they try to access the website from Domain A or Domain B, they both benefit of Cloudflare."

Probably would need more details in a support ticket. Based on what I'm reading, however, you can't point a domain not on CloudFlare to one on CloudFlare (can cause DNS resolution errors).

If the client doesn't want to switch the domain to us entirely, then they could look at doing a [CNAME setup](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168706-How-do-I-do-CNAME-setup-).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way, somehow, to have the Domain B linked to Cloudflare

Yes, you could have Domain B on Cloudflare if you control that domain.

> and their Domain A linked to the Domain B which is linked to Cloudflare ?

Technically yes, you could CNAME Domain A to Domain B, which is on Cloudflare.

However, this would likely fall afoul of:

> they don't want to link it to Cloudflare

They would have to modify the DNS for Domain A to do this, and if they don't want to link that domain to Cloudflare, I don't see why they would want to CNAME it to a domain that's on Cloudflare, which will effectively have the same outcome, if a little less efficient.

I see this problem as less of a technical problem and more of a client relations problem.  It sounds like you're trying to find sneaky ways of doing something the client expressly doesn't want.  It sounds like the proper solution would be to have an honest talk with the client about why you believe they should use Cloudflare (sell them on its benefits) and if they are still not interested, find a solution that doesn't involve Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

Really if both domain are in the seam server the solution is easy no cnames no complications
In config.php

```
 'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => 'DomainA.com', 'DomainB.com',
```

In the folder of DomainB

```
ln -s ../path/to/owncloud mycloud
```

Answer (score -2):

**Cloudflare** is a Nameserver, You can create a account and add desired Records like A, CNAME, TXT, MX.